# Очередность присвоения и смена ссылок на объекта

Tags: javascript, объекты

Встретил интересную задачу.

Задача: Чему будет равно foо.x?

```
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

Ответ: `undefined`.
Насколько я понимаю, `foo.x`, на последней строке, ссылается на старую ссылку `foo`, при этом, присваивая свойству `x` значение новой ссылки `foo`. Как в этом случае работает присвоение и замена ссылки для `foo`?

Comment: В С/С++ модификация выражения в левой части (`foo.x`) во время вычисления правой части (`foo = {n: 2}`) - неопределённое поведение. В случае JavaScript поведение скорее всего определено, но может зависеть от интерпретатора. Мойте руки перед едой и не мешайте побочные эффекты с вычислениями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [спецификации](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

1. выражение `foo.x = foo = {n: 2};` рассматривается как `foo.x = (foo = {n: 2});`
2. при выполнении присваивания `leftExpression = expressin`:

   1. сначала вычисляется leftExpression, для получения места *куда присваивать*
   2. затем вычисляется expressin
   3. выполняется непосредственно присваивание.

Для примера в вопросе

1. "вычисляется" `foo.x` - в данном случае `foo` это объект сохраненный в `bar`
2. "вычисляется" `foo = {n: 2}`

   1. вычисляется `foo` -  в данном случае это объект сохраненный в `bar`
   2. вычисляется `{n: 2}`
   3. в переменную `foo` присваивается значения из `2.1`
3. в сохраненную `foo` в поле `x` присваивается значение вычисленное в пункте 2

Таким образом, ссылка на новый `foo` доступна через переменную `bar`

```js
var foo = {
  n: 1
};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {
  n: 2
};

console.log(foo);
console.log(bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот объяснение, которое я нашел для себя.

```
foo.x = (foo = {n: 2});
```

1. На первом этапе вычисляется `leftExpression`, а это `foo.x`

> leftExpression = expression

2. Далее вычисляется права часть `expression`. Для этого выражения  `foo` становится ссылкой на новый объект
   (foo = {n: 2})
3. Вычисления из первого пункта становятся недействительны. Поскольку, чтобы в `foo.x` было что-то записано, нужно чтобы ссылка на объект существовала, а она только что была изменена при этом присвоении: `foo = {n: 2}`.
4. Исходя из пункта 3: смотрим `foo.x` выдается `undefined`, как и должно было.
5. При этом во время присвоения `foo.x` эта же ссылка все еще сохранена в bar, поэтому в bar будет создано новое свойство x со значением в виде ссылки на объект `{n: 2}`. В результате чего `bar.x == foo` выдаст `true` (одна и та же ссылка на объект)